# How to reload/refresh all screens in IOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app have many graphs on 5 screens , on "refresh button" in first screen I want to refresh all graph, all other stuff in all screens (in short on button click I want app as I see it when it first time load)

For one screen I can do this by calling viewDidLoad on button click,   but i want to do this on all screen on single click

Is there any way to do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 0):

that is very bad practice.
You should NEVER call viewDidLoad directly and why you need to reload all invisible screens at the same time?
Fetch the data if the screen is comming visible (viewWillAppear) and reload your UI-Components.

Comment: Thanks, But my app has refresh button , on that button click all work done on all screen should reset, and all data is already fetched on all screens

Comment: Then reload your datasource and fetch the reloaded data if needed. Maybe I'm wrong, but you don't show all views parallel?

Comment: yes I can do that , but I have taken super class (viewController) for al that five screens and I have fetch datasource in that super class because otherwise i have to fetch same data 5 times, and I have to reset all UI component   also like on off switch, if in some screen it is on at any screen then it should be off after clicking refresh button